# Unity.AutoRegistration - registers only interfaces and types with the same name

Tags: .net, unity-container, auto-registration

[Unity.AutoRegistration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) works fine when a type name matches an interface name, for example, `TClass` and `ITClass`. I want interface names go without prefix "T", like `IClass` and need that `IClass` to match `TClass`.

But when I rename the interface, the auto-registration fails. Do I have to match the type/interface names, or is there a way to accomplish my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with the author, here is the required code:

```
UContainer
    .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
    .LoadAssemblyFrom(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
    .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
    .Include(If.ImplementsITypeName, Then.Register())
    .Include(
        type => type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.StartsWith("I") && i.Name.Substring(1) == type.Name.Substring(1)), Then.Register())
    .Include(If.ImplementsSingleInterface, Then.Register())
    .ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for AutoRegistration has not been touched for a very long time. The [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity) contains an enhanced configuration engine for Unity that started as a port of StructureMap's configuration. This engine also supports conventions for registration.

One of the default conventions registers the class `MyService` as implementation of the interface `IMyService`. It looks as simple as that:

```cs
public class ImplementsIInterfaceNameConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
  public void Process(Type type, ConfigurationBuilder builder)
  {
    if (!type.IsConcrete())
    {
      return;
    }
    Type pluginType = FindPluginType(type);
    if (pluginType != null && 
        Constructor.HasConstructors(type))
    {
      builder.For(pluginType).Add(type).Named(type.FullName);
    }
  }
  private static Type FindPluginType(Type concreteType)
  {
    string interfaceName = "I" + concreteType.Name;
    Type[] interfaces = concreteType.GetInterfaces();
    return Array.Find(interfaces, t => t.Name == interfaceName);
  }
}
```

If you need some custom naming convention it would be very easy to modify the sample above. Using that convention to configure your container would look something like this:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.Scan(s => 
          {
            s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            s.With(new MyCustomConvention());
          });
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(builder);
```